# Lattice simplification

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory, integer-lattices

Update: There is an answer on same question I posted on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440261/graph-lattice-simplification).

I'm working on a data structure for the graph cut algorithm. The problem is to make different cuts on the shortest paths. I made a data structure for which I'm not sure about properties.

The input is a directed graph of shortest paths, which is a bounded lattice, partially ordered set with a minimum and a maximum element.

Define *next node N(n)* of node n as a set of nodes b for which a < b and there is no c with a < c < b. Similarly, define *previous node P(n)*. Extend definitions on sets, N(S) union of N(n) for $n \in S$, and similarly for P(S).

It is easy to make different cuts on list of set of nodes $L, N(L), N(N(L)), ...$ where for each neighboring pair of sets A, N(A)=B holds that there is no partition of $A=A_1 \cup A_2$ and $B=B_1 \cup B_2$ with $B_i = N(A_i)$, $A_i = P(B_i)$ for $i=1,2$.

With this property create new lattice with mapping:

- sub-lattice to one node
- if upper partition is found create partition cardinality number of edges.

In simple, algorithm for lattice -> lattice mapping is:

```
A = {minimum node}
new_node = [A]
1:
while A, N(A) don't have partitions
  append N(A) to new_node
  A = N(A)
for each partition $B_i$
  last_new_node = new_node
  create new_node = [B_i]
  create edge last_new_node to new_node
  go to 1
At the end fix maximum node in new lattice if needed
```

This algorithm can be called repeatedly on new lattices. I'm concern about:

- Is there guaranty to reach one-node lattice?
- Is there any measure of number of iterations to reach one-node lattice? It seams to me that bound is diameter of input graph.

I appreciate link to any similar data structure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440261/graph-lattice-simplification/5978469#5978469) on same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440261/graph-lattice-simplification) I posted on Stack Overflow.

Structure I was looking for is [series-parallel partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_partial_order).

Comment: Great! Thank you. I removed my comments to your question, as they were no longer relevant.

Comment: It is not so easy to answer your own question with a short comment, it is automatically set as a comment to question :-)